# Can't find mistake in upload image code php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to implement image upload in php. I have looked through some articles, but I can't find mistake in my code. `websitename/upload_avatar.php` appears in address bar, but path of image doesn't appear in MySQL table. What is wrong here?

HTML form:

```
  <form action="upload_avatar.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="FILE" onchange="this.form.submit()"  name="ava" value=""></form>
```

In `upload_avatar.php` :

```
<?php
     include ("bd.php");
     if (empty($_FILES['ava']['name']))
     {
    $avatar = "avatars/default.jpg"; 
     }
     else
    {
    $path_directory = 'avatars/';
    if(preg_match('/[.](JPG)|(jpg)|(jpeg)|(JPEG)|(gif)|(GIF)|(png)|(PNG)$/',$_FILES['ava']['name']))
    { 
    $filename = $_FILES['ava']['name'];
    $source = $_FILES['ava']['tmp_name'];
    $target = $path_directory . $filename;
    move_uploaded_file($source, $target);

     if(preg_match('/[.](GIF)|(gif)$/', $filename)) {
     $im = imagecreatefromgif($path_directory.$filename) ;
     }
      if(preg_match('/[.](PNG)|(png)$/', $filename)) {
      $im = imagecreatefrompng($path_directory.$filename) ;
      }  

        if(preg_match('/[.](JPG)|(jpg)|(jpeg)|(JPEG)$/', $filename)) {

        $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($path_directory.$filename);
     }
    $w = 150;
    $w_src = imagesx($im); 
    $h_src = imagesy($im); 
    $dest = imagecreatetruecolor($w,$w);
    if ($w_src>$h_src)

             imagecopyresampled($dest, $im, 0, 0,

             round((max($w_src,$h_src)-min($w_src,$h_src))/2),

             0, $w, $w, min($w_src,$h_src), min($w_src,$h_src));


    if ($w_src < $h_src)

             imagecopyresampled($dest, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $w,

             min($w_src,$h_src), min($w_src,$h_src));
             if ($w_src==$h_src)

             imagecopyresampled($dest, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $w, $w_src, $w_src);





    $date=time();



    imagejpeg($dest, $path_directory.$date.".jpg");



    $avatar = $path_directory.$date.".jpg";



    $delfull = $path_directory.$filename;

    unlink ($delfull);


    $result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO users (avatar) VALUES('$avatar')");

    }

    else

    {





    exit ("Image must be <strong>JPG,GIF or PNG</strong>");

     }


    }


    ?>
```

Comment: i could guess if(preg_match('/[.](JPG)|(jpg)|(jpeg)|(JPEG)|(gif)|(GIF)|(png)|(PNG)$/',$_FILES['ava']['name'])) is not called, you try to put echo "haha" inside this condition to see if it is called

Comment: @onegun right, it's not called. why? where is my mistake?

Comment: as mentioned, preg_match problem, the regex, i think "." need to be escaped

Comment: @onegun see no difference

Comment: or dont use preg_match, $path = $_FILES['ava']['name'];
$ext = strtolower(pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); then compare extension

Answer (score 0):

This is a very robust routine that creates 2 images  preview and big.

**It also checks the 3 image types for the smallest output.**  I do not care what format the image is as I put it in the HTML page as base64.

It also converts the images to base64 and save them in an SQL table and save the base64 image to an HTML page.

While it does the scaling the pics are displayed for review.

You seem to have enough knowledge about this to understand my code.

I may comment it.

```
$thumbWidth = 60;
$thumbHeight = 60;  
$previewWidth = 200;
$previewHeight = 150;
$bigWidth = 800;
$bigHeight = 600;


if( is_uploaded_file($_FILES['ava']['tmp_name']) || !($_FILES['ava']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK)){
  $save = false;
  $jspan = '';
  $gspan = '';
  $pspan = '';
```

**Get the type of image by its MIME Type.**

**Then recheck using imagecreatefrom**

**Regardless of extension, MIME Type, if it is an image jpg,png,or gif, it will positively identify the type.**

```
  switch(strtolower($_FILES['ava']['type'])){
  case 'image/jpeg':
    $image = @imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['ava']['tmp_name']);
    if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
  case 'image/png':
    $image = @imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['ava']['tmp_name']);
    if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
  case 'image/gif':
    $image = @imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['ava']['tmp_name']);
    if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
  default:
    $img = @getimagesize($_FILES['ava']['tmp_name']);
    switch(strtolower($img['mime'])){
    case 'image/jpeg':
      $image = @imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['ava']['tmp_name']);
      if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
    case 'image/png':
      $image = @imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['ava']['tmp_name']);
      if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
    case 'image/gif':
      $image = @imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['ava']['tmp_name']);
      if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
    default:
      $filename = $_FILES['ava']['name'];
      $ext = substr($filename,-3);
      switch(strtolower($ext)){
      case 'jpg':
        $image = @imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['ava']['tmp_name']);
        if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
      case 'gif':
        $image = @imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['ava']['tmp_name']);
        if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
      case 'png':
        $image = @imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['ava']['tmp_name']);
        if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
      default:
        $image = @imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['ava']['tmp_name']);
        if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
        $image = @imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['ava']['tmp_name']);
        if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
        $image = @imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['ava']['tmp_name']);
        if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Scale to the Preview size**

```
 if ($save === true){
  $originalWidth  = imagesx($image);
  $originalHeight = imagesy($image);
  $scale      = min($previewWidth/$originalWidth, $previewHeight/$originalHeight);
  $newWidth  = ceil($scale*$originalWidth);
  $newHeight = ceil($scale*$originalHeight);
  $newPic = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
  imagecopyresampled($newPic, $image,0, 0, 0, 0,$newWidth, $newHeight, $originalWidth, $originalHeight);
  ob_start();
  imagejpeg($newPic, NULL, 70);
  $jpg = ob_get_clean();
  ob_clean();
  ob_end_flush();
  $jLen = strlen($jpg);
  ob_start();
  imagepng($newPic, NULL, 9);
  $png = ob_get_clean();
  ob_clean();
  ob_end_flush();
  $pLen = strlen($png);
  ob_start();
  imagegif($newPic);
  $gif = ob_get_clean();
  ob_clean();
  ob_end_flush();
```

**Check which image type creates smallest number of bytes**

```
  $gLen = strlen($gif);
  if ($gLen < $jLen){
    if ($pLen < $gLen){
      $raw = $png;
      $png = null;
      $type = 'png';
      $pspan = '<span class="size">';
    }
    else{
      $raw = $gif;
      $gif = null;
      $type = 'gif';
      $gspan = '<span class="size">';
    }
  }
  elseif($pLen < $jLen){
    $raw = $png;
    $png = null;
    $type = 'png';
    $pspan = '<span class="size">';
  }
  else{
    $raw = $jpg;
    $jpg = null;
    $type = 'jpg';
    $jspan = '<span class="size">';
  }
```

**Convert to bas64 and Save**

I use base64 images in my HTML pages.  It eliminates HTTP round trip for each image.

The naysayers complain base64 adds 30% to the image size. And it does.

When the base64 is embedded in the HTML, it get zgipped. And the extra 30% is compressed by gzip to much less, typicality only a few percent.

An HTTP Round trip varies from server to server, time of day etc. but typically 200 milliseconds.  The transmission time of the base64 is usually just a few milliseconds.

```
  $base64 = base64_encode($raw);
  $thumb1 = "<img  width=\"$newWidth\" height=\"$newHeight\" src=\"data:image/$type;base64,$base64\"  alt =\"profile thumb one\"/>";
  $size = 'Thumb';
  echo  "<p>Image $num $size <br>$jspan jpg: $jLen bytes</span>, <br>$gspan gif: $gLen bytes</span>, <br>$pspan png: $pLen bytes</span></p> $thumb1"; 
  $filename = 'thumb1.' . $type;
  $fp = fopen($filename  ,"w");
  fwrite($fp, $raw);
  fclose($fp);
  imagedestroy($newPic);
  $filename = "thumb1_$type.html";
  $fp = fopen($filename  ,"w");
  fwrite($fp, $thumb1);
  fclose($fp);
  $thumb1 = mysql_escape_string($thumb1);
  @mysql_unbuffered_query("UPDATE `photos` SET `thumb1`='$thumb1' WHERE `id`=$id");
```

**Scale to Big Image:**

```
  $scale      = min($bigWidth/$originalWidth, $bigHeight/$originalHeight);
  $newWidth  = ceil($scale*$originalWidth);
  $newHeight = ceil($scale*$originalHeight);
  $newPic = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
  imagecopyresampled($newPic, $image,0, 0, 0, 0,$newWidth, $newHeight, $originalWidth, $originalHeight);
  ob_start();
  imagejpeg($newPic, NULL, 70);
  $jpg = ob_get_clean();
  ob_clean();
  ob_end_flush();
  $jLen = strlen($jpg);
  ob_start();
  imagepng($newPic, NULL, 9);
  $png = ob_get_clean();
  ob_clean();
  ob_end_flush();
  $pLen = strlen($png);
  ob_start();
  imagegif($newPic);
  $gif = ob_get_clean();
  ob_clean();
  ob_end_flush();
  $gLen = strlen($gif);
  if ($gLen < $jLen){
    if ($pLen < $gLen){
      $raw = $png;
      $png = null;
      $type = 'png';
      $pspan = '<span class="size">';
    }
    else{
      $raw = $gif;
      $gif = null;
      $type = 'gif';
      $gspan = '<span class="size">';
    }
  }
  elseif($pLen < $jLen){
    $raw = $png;
    $png = null;
    $type = 'png';
      $pspan = '<span class="size">';
  }
  else{
    $raw = $jpg;
    $jpg = null;
    $type = 'jpg';
    $jspan = '<span class="size">';
  }
  $base64 = base64_encode($raw);
  $size = 'Full Size';
  $filename = 'big1.' . $type;
  $big1 = "<img  width=\"$newWidth\" height=\"$newHeight\" src=\"data:image/$type;base64,$base64\" alt =\"profile photo one\"/>";
  echo  "<p>Image $num $size <br>$jspan jpg: $jLen bytes</span>, <br>$gspan gif: $gLen bytes</span>, <br>$pspan png: $pLen bytes</span></p> $big1"; 
  $fp = fopen($filename  ,"w");
  fwrite($fp, $raw);
  fclose($fp);
  imagedestroy($newPic);
  $filename = "big1_$type.html";
  $fp = fopen($filename  ,"w");
  fwrite($fp, $big1);
  fclose($fp);
  $big1 = mysql_escape_string($big1);
  @mysql_unbuffered_query("UPDATE `photos` SET `big1`='$big1' WHERE `id`=$id");
```