# Generate a thumbnail of any upload file

Tags: php, html, codeigniter-2

I have a website where users upload document files. I want to display thumbnails of these documents. How can I display the first page of a document file as an image using codeigniter?

Below is the controller code:

```
public function do_upload()
{
    require_once APPPATH . "php_include/authenticate.php";
    $path = "uploads/file_attachment/";
    if($_FILES['userfile']['name'] != ''){
        $image = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
        $ext = pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 
        $filename = basename($image,'.'.$ext);
        $filename = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "-", $filename);
        $image = $filename.'.'.$ext;
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"],$path.$image);
        $data = array(
            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'file' => $image,
        );
        $this->signupmodel->addfile($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: i need the preview of document files like (.doc,.txt,.pdf) not for the image file

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit of overkill for you but I described a bulletproof way to upload images.   There are all kinds of ways where the extension (.jpg, .gif) does not match the image.  Browsers have to do similar testing before rendering an image.

This code also chooses the most efficient image type to save it as and scales the image to multiple dimensions.

[Stackoverflow: Scaling Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28017062/cant-find-mistake-in-upload-image-code-php/28017133#28017133)